# Make 1 exception on X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN

Tags: .htaccess, iframe

I use
`Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN`
in .htaccess

But i would like to have 1 html page that isn't blocked when shown in iframe on other websites.....

How can i make 1 exception?

Comment: Wrap it into a `<FilesMatch>` directive with a negated regular expression, or stick it into an `<If>`with an appropriate condition, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Header` directive provides an additional argument that allows you to set the header conditionally based on whether an environment variable is set or not.

You could then set an env var when this one URL is requested. And only allow the header to be set when the env var is *not* set.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/one-page-not-blocked\.html$" DO_NOT_BLOCK

Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN env=!DO_NOT_BLOCK
```

The above `SetEnvIf` directive sets the env var `DO_NOT_BLOCK` to the value `1` when the regex matches the requested URL.

The `env=!DO_NOT_BLOCK` argument is successful when the env var is *not* set (denoted by the `!` prefix).

This method allows you to add additional URLs to not block by simply adding more `SetEnvIf` directives.